# How to hover Image using Canvas ? TKinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a code that is working perfectly on Label widget but i am quite confuse how to convert this to Canvas ?

This is what the code I have tried.

```
from tkinter import * 

def onObjectClick1(event):
    print("1")
    my_pic1 = PhotoImage(file="start000-before.png")
    obj1 = canv.create_image(50,50,image=my_pic1, anchor=NW)

def onObjectClick2(event):
    print("2")
    my_pic2 = PhotoImage(file="start000-after.png")
    obj2 = canv.create_image(50,50,image=my_pic2, anchor=NW)
    
root = Tk()    
canv = Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
my_pic1 = PhotoImage(file="start000-before.png")
obj1 = canv.create_image(50,50,image=my_pic1, anchor=NW)
canv.tag_bind(obj1, '<Enter>', onObjectClick1)        
canv.tag_bind(obj1, '<Leave>', onObjectClick2)        
canv.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I am new in Tkinter. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "hover image"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you want to do, but there are two things you are doing wrong. The first one is related to [this](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm). If you define a local variable inside your function to keep your image object you will lose track of it when leaving the function. The second is that you are creating new objects over the old object and then you will never be able to "enter" the object again. You can use `Canvas.itemconfig()` to change item image instead, but be careful with that because you will lose the item binding when doing it, so you need to do it again. Try this and see if it is what you were expecting:

```
from tkinter import * 

def onObjectClick1(event):
    print("1")
    canv.itemconfig(obj1, image=my_pic2)
    canv.tag_bind(obj1, '<Leave>', onObjectClick2)     

def onObjectClick2(event):
    print("2")
    canv.itemconfig(obj1, image=my_pic1)
    canv.tag_bind(obj1, '<Enter>', onObjectClick1)        
    
root = Tk()    
canv = Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
my_pic1 = PhotoImage(file="start000-before.png")
my_pic2 = PhotoImage(file="start000-after.png")

obj1 = canv.create_image(50,50,image=my_pic1, anchor=NW)
canv.tag_bind(obj1, '<Enter>', onObjectClick1)        
canv.tag_bind(obj1, '<Leave>', onObjectClick2)        
canv.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Bunch of Thanks! It's working exactly the way I want. I want to ask one more thing, Is it possible to provide slide In and slide Out transition to image inside the canvas ?

Comment: Yes but you will have to program that by hand. The same way you can change an image you can move it

Comment: But I'm overthinking about it and tkinter is not the best tool if you want to to do advanced designing like modern html webpages. Of course you can do, but at what cost?